# Цвет `ComboBox` при наведении

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В WPF приложении нужно добавить `ComboBox` в пользовательском стиле. Проблема в том, что стандартный контрол  при наведении мышкой выделяется синим сам и выделяет Items так же. Попробовал использовать стили, но бокс все равно работает как стандартный при наведении. В чем ошибка?

```
       <ComboBox x:Name="subjct_cmb" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="120" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayEA}" 
                  FontFamily="{StaticResource MainFont}" Background="#FF262626" >
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2E2E2E"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="About Programm" Background="{StaticResource Gray36}" Height="16"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="Report a Bug" Background="{StaticResource Gray36}" Height="16"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="Feedback" Background="{StaticResource Gray36}" Height="16"/>
            <ComboBoxItem  Content="Other" Background="{StaticResource Gray36}" Height="16"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

Результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @AresGod все тот же синий цвет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы всегда можете изменить стандартный шаблон контрола. Для этого нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на контрол в дизайнере, выберите <kbd>EditTempate</kbd>><kbd>Edit A Copy...</kbd>. В вашем случае предварительно откройте комбобокс (<kbd>ExpandCombobox</kbd>), нажмите правой кнопкой на элемент в выпавшем списке, выберите <kbd>EditTempate</kbd>><kbd>Edit A Copy...</kbd>. Появится простыня со шаблоном, где есть все. Вам в ней нужен последний триггер (по крайней мере у меня он последний). Выглядит он так:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="False" />
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                    Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            TargetName="Bd"
            Value="#5426A0DA" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            TargetName="Bd"
            Value="#FF26A0DA" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Вам нужно заменить цвет в `Property="Background"` (`#5426A0DA`) на ваш. Теперь шаблон готов. Используйте его, например, так:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemControlTemplate1}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Код полностью:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemControlTemplate1"
                         TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                         Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                                   Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#1F26A0DA" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#A826A0DA" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                                   Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#3D26A0DA" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#FF26A0DA" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#2E0080FF" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#99006CD9" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                                   Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#3DDADADA" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#FFDADADA" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                                   Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#FF26A0DA" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                   Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                                   Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#FF2E2E2E" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="#FF26A0DA" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemControlTemplate1}"></Setter>
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="20"
                  Width="120"
                  Background="#FF262626"
                  IsDropDownOpen="True">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="About Programm"
                          Height="16" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Report a Bug"
                          Height="16" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Feedback"
                          Height="16" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Other"
                          Height="16" />
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А по части `ComboBox` при наведении, какое проперти отвечает ? Не `ComboBoxValue` а сам бокс ?

Comment: @Сергей для этого сгенерируйте шаблон самого комбобокса (простыня будет побольше раза в 4), там надо искать.

Comment: Template или Style ?

Comment: @Сергей создастся новый `ControlTemplate` для комбобокса

Comment: Все что создается так     это   `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid/>
        </ControlTemplate>`

Comment: @Сергей вы делаете как я писал во втором предложении?

Comment: Я делаю так: правой кнопкой по комбобоксу - > правка шаблона - > создать пустой.  выходит окно Создание ресурса Control Template -> ок. По итогу в App.xaml* добавляется только 2строки :   `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid/>
        </ControlTemplate>` может в нем нужно с нуля писать все ?

Comment: @Сергей "Edit A Copy..." переводится примерно как "редактировать копию", но никак не "создать пустой"

Comment: Edit A Copy создает Style а не Template. или я что то путаю

Comment: @Сергей да, Style, увидел. Но дальше в недрах есть `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">` и `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate"                          TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">`

Comment: т.е. - `x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"` затем `x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate"` и затем `x:Key="ComboBoxStyle"` вот эта вся простыня шаблон  для `Combobox`?

Comment: @Сергей да, можно настроить что угодно

Comment: Не могу найти код отвечающий за отображение прямоугольника со скругленными углами и градиент при наведении на сам контрол. Если не трудно - ответе в новом вопросе -
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726473/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-combobox